# setting ssh permission in hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, ssh, elastic-map-reduce

I'm trying to install hadoop for the first time and I'm following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrxQXfE7t9A & https://sites.google.com/site/howtohadoop/how-to-install-hdp#bmec2

What I'm trying to do is setting up the master node to access the other slave node. So, when it comes to set the permission for the /root/.ssh folder by "chmod 700 /root/.ssh" an error message  is displayed that I do not have permission.

I couldn't understand why this message? Why I do not have permission?

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permission since **you are not logged in as root** and trying to play with the files owned by root. 
Run `sudo chmod 700 /root/.ssh` . **sudo**  makes you run commands as **root** on the system.